# CSS and other errors when switching to production rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css

I started to migrate a Ruby on Rails/Backbone.js app to production today and got a large number of new problems. One was the following CSS line:

```
#crops input[type=text, class=crop_selector] {
      width:140px;
}
```

This was OK in development, but in production it isn't. On top of that, many of my images no longer appeared in the browser and I'm seeing no background colors. Could someone explain to me 
    1) what is wrong with the CSS?
    2) what is so different about production? (perhaps point me to docs where I could read up on the differences)

EDIT on 1/24/13: someone helped me with the CSS error, so that is no longer a question. I still need to understand exactly what is different about production, when the switch is made. It is not just environment variables.

Comment: syntax: `#crops input.crop_selector[type='text']`

Comment: @Eru, thanks very  much. That certainly fixes the CSS problem. I don't understand why this error popped up in production but not in development, though.

Comment: It seems like you have 2 questions about 2 totally different things.  You should really write ... 2 questions.